# Can't create non-infinite loop starting from infinite loop

Tags: c++, arduino

Second edit: I've now somehow managed to let the script run (changing int main(void) to int main()) with a defined "for", however it egregiously ignores me and runs endlessly anyways:

```
int main() { // was int main(void)!!
    // We'll start by performing hardware and peripheral setup.
    SetupHardware();
    // We'll then enable global interrupts for our use.
    GlobalInterruptEnable();
    //int counter = 0;
    //int x_times = 1000;

    // Once that's done, we'll enter an infinite loop.
for (day = 0;day = 2;day++) // RE-ENABLE THIS TO PUT THE INFINITE LOOP BACK IN!
    // trying to make a loop that will only run a certain number of times (5)...
{
        // We need to run our task to process and deliver data for our IN and OUT endpoints.
        HID_Task();
        // We also need to run the main USB management task.
        USB_USBTask();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit 1: with some clarifications:

This code is taken from a project to make the Arduino look like a joystick for the Nintendo Switch, based off https://github.com/shinyquagsire23/Switch-Fightstick .

I think the Arduino is using a different firmware from the one it comes with, as the whole script is flashed on the Arduino after 'make' compiles a .hex file including Joystick.c and other scripts as well. I'll include the entire content of Joystick.c below with comments from the original developer in hopes of adding clarity to this request.

```
/*
Nintendo Switch Fightstick - Proof-of-Concept

Based on the LUFA library's Low-Level Joystick Demo
    (C) Dean Camera
Based on the HORI's Pokken Tournament Pro Pad design
    (C) HORI

This project implements a modified version of HORI's Pokken Tournament Pro Pad
USB descriptors to allow for the creation of custom controllers for the
Nintendo Switch. This also works to a limited degree on the PS3.

Since System Update v3.0.0, the Nintendo Switch recognizes the Pokken
Tournament Pro Pad as a Pro Controller. Physical design limitations prevent
the Pokken Controller from functioning at the same level as the Pro
Controller. However, by default most of the descriptors are there, with the
exception of Home and Capture. Descriptor modification allows us to unlock
these buttons for our use.
*/

#include "Joystick.h"

typedef enum {
    UP,
    DOWN,
    LEFT,
    RIGHT,
    X,
    Y,
    A,
    B,
    L,
    R,
    THROW,
    NOTHING,
    TRIGGERS,
    HOME
} Buttons_t;

typedef struct {
    Buttons_t button;
    uint16_t duration;
} command;

static const command step[] = {
    // Setup controller
    { NOTHING,  250 },
    { TRIGGERS,   5 },
    { NOTHING,  150 },
    { TRIGGERS,   5 },
    { NOTHING,  150 },
    { TRIGGERS,   5 },
    { NOTHING,  250 },

    // Talk to Pondo
    { NOTHING,   100 },
    { A,          10 }, // Start
    { NOTHING,    20 },
    { A,          10 },
    { NOTHING,    20 },
    { A,          10 },
    { NOTHING,    20 },
    { A,          10 },
    { NOTHING,    50 },
    { HOME,       10 },
    { NOTHING,    30 },
    { DOWN,        5 },
    { NOTHING,     5 },
    { RIGHT,       5 },
    { NOTHING,     5 },
    { RIGHT,       5 },
    { NOTHING,     5 },
    { RIGHT,       5 },
    { NOTHING,     5 },
    { RIGHT,       5 },
    { NOTHING,     5 },
    { A,          10 },
    { NOTHING,    20 },
    { DOWN,       60 },
    { NOTHING,     5 },
    { A,          10 },
    { NOTHING,     5 },
    { DOWN,        5 },
    { NOTHING,     5 },
    { DOWN,        5 },
    { NOTHING,     5 },
    { DOWN,        5 },
    { NOTHING,     5 },
    { DOWN,        5 },
    { NOTHING,     5 },
    { A,          10 },
    { NOTHING,    10 },
    { DOWN,        5 },
    { NOTHING,     5 },
    { DOWN,        5 },
    { NOTHING,     5 },
    { A,          10 },
    { NOTHING,    10 },
    { UP,          5 },
    { NOTHING,     5 },
    { A,          10 },
    { NOTHING,     5 },
    { A,          10 },
    { NOTHING,     5 },
    { A,          10 },
    { NOTHING,     5 },
    { A,          10 },
    { NOTHING,     5 },
    { A,          10 },
    { NOTHING,     5 },
    { A,          10 },
    { NOTHING,     5 },
    { HOME,       10 },
    { NOTHING,    20 },
    { HOME,       10 },
    { NOTHING,    30 },
    { B,          10 },
    { NOTHING,    20 },
    { A   ,       10 },
    { NOTHING,   100 }
};

// Main entry point.
int main(void) {
    // We'll start by performing hardware and peripheral setup.
    SetupHardware();
    // We'll then enable global interrupts for our use.
    GlobalInterruptEnable();
    // Once that's done, we'll enter an infinite loop.
    for (;;)
    {
        // We need to run our task to process and deliver data for our IN and OUT endpoints.
        HID_Task();
        // We also need to run the main USB management task.
        USB_USBTask();
    }
}

// Configures hardware and peripherals, such as the USB peripherals.
void SetupHardware(void) {
    // We need to disable watchdog if enabled by bootloader/fuses.
    MCUSR &= ~(1 << WDRF);
    wdt_disable();

    // We need to disable clock division before initializing the USB hardware.
    clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1);
    // We can then initialize our hardware and peripherals, including the USB stack.

    #ifdef ALERT_WHEN_DONE
    // Both PORTD and PORTB will be used for the optional LED flashing and buzzer.
    #warning LED and Buzzer functionality enabled. All pins on both PORTB and \
PORTD will toggle when printing is done.
    DDRD  = 0xFF; //Teensy uses PORTD
    PORTD =  0x0;
                  //We'll just flash all pins on both ports since the UNO R3
    DDRB  = 0xFF; //uses PORTB. Micro can use either or, but both give us 2 LEDs
    PORTB =  0x0; //The ATmega328P on the UNO will be resetting, so unplug it?
    #endif
    // The USB stack should be initialized last.
    USB_Init();
}

// Fired to indicate that the device is enumerating.
void EVENT_USB_Device_Connect(void) {
    // We can indicate that we're enumerating here (via status LEDs, sound, etc.).
}

// Fired to indicate that the device is no longer connected to a host.
void EVENT_USB_Device_Disconnect(void) {
    // We can indicate that our device is not ready (via status LEDs, sound, etc.).
}

// Fired when the host set the current configuration of the USB device after enumeration.
void EVENT_USB_Device_ConfigurationChanged(void) {
    bool ConfigSuccess = true;

    // We setup the HID report endpoints.
    ConfigSuccess &= Endpoint_ConfigureEndpoint(JOYSTICK_OUT_EPADDR, EP_TYPE_INTERRUPT, JOYSTICK_EPSIZE, 1);
    ConfigSuccess &= Endpoint_ConfigureEndpoint(JOYSTICK_IN_EPADDR, EP_TYPE_INTERRUPT, JOYSTICK_EPSIZE, 1);

    // We can read ConfigSuccess to indicate a success or failure at this point.
}

// Process control requests sent to the device from the USB host.
void EVENT_USB_Device_ControlRequest(void) {
    // We can handle two control requests: a GetReport and a SetReport.

    // Not used here, it looks like we don't receive control request from the Switch.
}

// Process and deliver data from IN and OUT endpoints.
void HID_Task(void) {
    // If the device isn't connected and properly configured, we can't do anything here.
    if (USB_DeviceState != DEVICE_STATE_Configured)
        return;

    // We'll start with the OUT endpoint.
    Endpoint_SelectEndpoint(JOYSTICK_OUT_EPADDR);
    // We'll check to see if we received something on the OUT endpoint.
    if (Endpoint_IsOUTReceived())
    {
        // If we did, and the packet has data, we'll react to it.
        if (Endpoint_IsReadWriteAllowed())
        {
            // We'll create a place to store our data received from the host.
            USB_JoystickReport_Output_t JoystickOutputData;
            // We'll then take in that data, setting it up in our storage.
            while(Endpoint_Read_Stream_LE(&JoystickOutputData, sizeof(JoystickOutputData), NULL) != ENDPOINT_RWSTREAM_NoError);
            // At this point, we can react to this data.

            // However, since we're not doing anything with this data, we abandon it.
        }
        // Regardless of whether we reacted to the data, we acknowledge an OUT packet on this endpoint.
        Endpoint_ClearOUT();
    }

    // We'll then move on to the IN endpoint.
    Endpoint_SelectEndpoint(JOYSTICK_IN_EPADDR);
    // We first check to see if the host is ready to accept data.
    if (Endpoint_IsINReady())
    {
        // We'll create an empty report.
        USB_JoystickReport_Input_t JoystickInputData;
        // We'll then populate this report with what we want to send to the host.
        GetNextReport(&JoystickInputData);
        // Once populated, we can output this data to the host. We do this by first writing the data to the control stream.
        while(Endpoint_Write_Stream_LE(&JoystickInputData, sizeof(JoystickInputData), NULL) != ENDPOINT_RWSTREAM_NoError);
        // We then send an IN packet on this endpoint.
        Endpoint_ClearIN();
    }
}

typedef enum {
    SYNC_CONTROLLER,
    SYNC_POSITION,
    BREATHE,
    PROCESS,
    CLEANUP,
    DONE
} State_t;
State_t state = SYNC_CONTROLLER;

#define ECHOES 2
int echoes = 0;
USB_JoystickReport_Input_t last_report;

int report_count = 0;
int xpos = 0;
int ypos = 0;
int bufindex = 0;
int duration_count = 0;
int portsval = 0;

// Prepare the next report for the host.
void GetNextReport(USB_JoystickReport_Input_t* const ReportData) {

    // Prepare an empty report
    memset(ReportData, 0, sizeof(USB_JoystickReport_Input_t));
    ReportData->LX = STICK_CENTER;
    ReportData->LY = STICK_CENTER;
    ReportData->RX = STICK_CENTER;
    ReportData->RY = STICK_CENTER;
    ReportData->HAT = HAT_CENTER;

    // Repeat ECHOES times the last report
    if (echoes > 0)
    {
        memcpy(ReportData, &last_report, sizeof(USB_JoystickReport_Input_t));
        echoes--;
        return;
    }

    // States and moves management
    switch (state)
    {

        case SYNC_CONTROLLER:
            state = BREATHE;
            break;


        case SYNC_POSITION:
            bufindex = 0;


            ReportData->Button = 0;
            ReportData->LX = STICK_CENTER;
            ReportData->LY = STICK_CENTER;
            ReportData->RX = STICK_CENTER;
            ReportData->RY = STICK_CENTER;
            ReportData->HAT = HAT_CENTER;


            state = BREATHE;
            break;

        case BREATHE:
            state = PROCESS;
            break;

        case PROCESS:

            switch (step[bufindex].button)
            {

                case UP:
                    ReportData->LY = STICK_MIN;
                    break;

                case LEFT:
                    ReportData->LX = STICK_MIN;
                    break;

                case DOWN:
                    ReportData->LY = STICK_MAX;
                    break;

                case RIGHT:
                    ReportData->LX = STICK_MAX;
                    break;

                case A:
                    ReportData->Button |= SWITCH_A;
                    break;

                case B:
                    ReportData->Button |= SWITCH_B;
                    break;

                case R:
                    ReportData->Button |= SWITCH_R;
                    break;

                case THROW:
                    ReportData->LY = STICK_MIN;
                    ReportData->Button |= SWITCH_R;
                    break;

                case TRIGGERS:
                    ReportData->Button |= SWITCH_L | SWITCH_R;
                    break;

                case HOME:
                    ReportData->Button |= SWITCH_HOME;
                    break;

                default:
                    ReportData->LX = STICK_CENTER;
                    ReportData->LY = STICK_CENTER;
                    ReportData->RX = STICK_CENTER;
                    ReportData->RY = STICK_CENTER;
                    ReportData->HAT = HAT_CENTER;
                    break;
            }

            duration_count++;

            if (duration_count > step[bufindex].duration)
            {
                bufindex++;
                duration_count = 0;
            }


            if (bufindex > (int)( sizeof(step) / sizeof(step[0])) - 1)
            {

                // state = CLEANUP;

                bufindex = 7;
                duration_count = 0;

                state = BREATHE;

                ReportData->LX = STICK_CENTER;
                ReportData->LY = STICK_CENTER;
                ReportData->RX = STICK_CENTER;
                ReportData->RY = STICK_CENTER;
                ReportData->HAT = HAT_CENTER;


                // state = DONE;
//              state = BREATHE;

            }

            break;

        case CLEANUP:
            state = DONE;
            break;

        case DONE:
            #ifdef ALERT_WHEN_DONE
            portsval = ~portsval;
            PORTD = portsval; //flash LED(s) and sound buzzer if attached
            PORTB = portsval;
            _delay_ms(250);
            #endif
            return;
    }


    // Prepare to echo this report
    memcpy(&last_report, ReportData, sizeof(USB_JoystickReport_Input_t));
    echoes = ECHOES;

}
```

Hi all, first time posting and mostly a C++ noob - please have mercy!

I think I have an unusual problem, in that I have a C++ script for an Arduino, which repeats itself indefinitely. I would like for this script to only execute itself a set number of times, but everything I've tried so far is failing.

This is the original piece of script with the infinite loop:

```
int main(void) {
    SetupHardware();
    GlobalInterruptEnable();
    for (;;)
    {
        HID_Task();
        USB_USBTask();
    }
}
```

And this is what I've tried so far, to make the script run just twice:

```
int main(void) {
    SetupHardware();
    GlobalInterruptEnable();
    int day = 0;
for (day = 0; day <= 2; day++)
{
        HID_Task();
        USB_USBTask();
    }
return; 
}
```

I've tried getting rid of "return", and according to 'make' the code looks ok, as I don't get any error message. However, when I flash the Arduino with this script, it doesn't work at all. The moment I restore the infinite loop, everything gets back to working normally (and endlessly).

For reference, here's the link to the GitHub project, the file I'm trying to edit is Joystick.c: https://github.com/bertrandom/snowball-thrower

I'm a bit lost and all ears/eyes for advice.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. `for (day = 0; day <= 2; day++)` will loop *three* times, not two. 2. Does Arduino take a `main` function? I thought they used a `setup()` and a `loop()`?

Comment: ***Does Arduino take a main function?*** That confused me as well. Must be using some alternate IDE

Comment: From C++ point of view, your loop seems ok. Try removing the loop completly and see wether it halts. If so, the culprit is most probably one of the first two lines

Comment: @Heyji, or one of the functions used in the `for` loop.

Comment: @R Sahu: no. If it halts without the loop, there is an issue in one of the first two lines. It could be that there is another issue in the for loop as well, in addition. But let's look at the problems one by one, from the beginning to the end.

Comment: What does *it doesn't work at all* mean? If you only run the loop twice maybe it shuts down before having time to do anything. I seems like you have assumed the error is in the loop, while it most likely is in how the rest of the code works.

Comment: I've made some edits to the post in hopes to add more clarity to this request. Thanks!

Comment: @Heyji I tried your suggestion and I can confirm that removing the loop halts the script! Could it be that the lines in the loop take an extended time to "process" somehow?

Comment: @Seifz: Halt means it stops and never returns. If it is how you understood "halt", then it means that there is an issue in one of the first two functions. Repeat the process to decide whether the issue is in the first or second function. To debug further, you need a mean to interract with your software otherwise you won't get far. I do not know Arduino well, but maybe there is some sort of decoder, of some IO you could write to in order to check where your program halts. (if the comment helps, you might vote it up as well by the way)

Comment: @Heyji thanks, at this point I'd say it's hard for me to say if the script actually "halts" or doesn't do anything at all. I'll scout for an IO to see if it can be debugged. Per my latest edit, I've even got the script to work with a non-infinite loop, but it keeps on running endlessly even after specifying a limit. I'm no expert, but as you're saying the issue should be within those two functions.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try changing the script to

```
int main(void) {
    SetupHardware();
    GlobalInterruptEnable();
    int counter = 0;
    int x_times = 1000;
    for (;;)
    {
        HID_Task();
        USB_USBTask();
        ++counter;
        if (counter >= x_times) return;
    }
}
```

and see if it works to some degree?

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately nothing happens

Comment: Could you increase the x_times to 10000? As we keep increasing it, it should keep approximate to the infinite loop working case.

Comment: Thanks again - I've increased it up to 65000 and nothing happens. If I set x_times to 70000 or more, I get an overflow warning when compiling.